# Box chars characters (Missing character: There is no ┬ in font)

Tags: fonts, listings, unicode, verbatim, sphinx

I am using Sphinx to build a project that use listings and some box characters. I have these errors:

```
Missing character: There is no ─ in font [lmmono9-regular]:!
Missing character: There is no ┬ in font [lmmono9-regular]:!
Missing character: There is no ─ in font [lmmono9-regular]:!
Missing character: There is no ┦ in font [lmmono9-regular]:!
Missing character: There is no │ in font [lmmono9-regular]:!
Missing character: There is no │ in font [lmmono9-regular]:!
```

For example I have this in my RST files:

```
.. code-block:: text

    ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
    │0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1│ = 0b1010011 = 83
    └─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

Which is transpiled into:

```
\begin{sphinxVerbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1│ = 0b1010011 = 83
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
\end{sphinxVerbatim}
```

What can I change to support normal unicode chars?

I build the tex file with:

```
latexmk -xelatex -pdf main.tex
```

Comment: you need to find a font which has the chars and then use it as typewriter font.

Comment: `\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` might work for you, but without a [MWE,](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) we can’t test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{lstfiracode}

\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}
```